# OAuth error when accessing BigQuery table from Google sheets in Google Cloud client library

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table imported from Google SpreadSheets (created from BigQuery Web UI). I (my Google account) am the owner of both the Sheets and the Cloud projects. I tied to access the BQ table using Python client library (according to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python)), but I met the error `error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Errors: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.` Meanwhile, the authentication works when I query other BQ tables, such as those imported from csv. May I know what I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Accessing data hosted within Google Drive requires an additional OAuth scope

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive